# Try/Catch in mulitple awaits in express app

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

I am making a few database calls and I am using `async/await` and `try/catch` for error handling. I am struggling if I should have all of the db calls in one `try/catch, or have multiple` try/catch` blocks for each call.

I also have a few calls in callback fncs, I am not confident those calls will be caught in my catch block if I only have one `try/catch`. With that in mind, those calls have their own try catch block. Here is a working example:

```
exports.syncStaff = async function (req, res, next) {
  // ShiftTask && Shift is a model from mongoose
  try {
    // DB CALL #1 --> Inside of Try/Catch Block
    const shift = await Shift.findById(req.params.id);
    // DB CALL #2 + 3 --> Two calls run in parallel --> Inside of Try/Catch Block
    const [shiftTasks, shiftType] = await Promise.all([
      ShiftTask.find({ group: shift.id }),
      mongoose.model('ShiftType').findById(shift.type).populate('tasks').select('tasks')
    ]);

    await Promise.all(shiftTasks.filter(st => !shiftType.workshops.find(type => type.id.toString() === st.task.toString() || st.status !== 'pending')).map(task => {
      // DB CALL #4 --> Separate Try/Catch Block, is this needed?
      try { 
        return ShiftTask.remove({ _id: task.id });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error);
      }
    }));

    await Promise.all(shiftType.workshops.filter(type => !shiftTasks.find(task => task.shift.toString() === type.id.toString())).map(type => {
      try {
        // DB CALL #5 -- Separate Try/Catch Block, is this needed?
        return ShiftTask.create({
          group: shift.id,
          eventType: type.id
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        next(error);
      }
    }));
    return await res.status(201).json('still to be decided');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Are the try/catch blocks in db calls #4 and #5 necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling errors in nodejs in (nested) try/catch/finally blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686364/handling-errors-in-nodejs-in-nested-try-catch-finally-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think external try catch blocks are needed. If an error is thrown from somewhere, it can be caught from the block in the public container. I made an example like this. You can test the 2nd case specified in the code from the google chrome console.

```js
let compPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Complete');
});

let errPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject(new Error("Whoops promise reject!"))
});

let exec = async () => {

    try {

        let res1 = await compPromise;
        console.log('res1', res1);
        let [res2,res3] = await Promise.all([
            compPromise,
            compPromise
        ])
        console.log('res2', res2);
        console.log('res3', res3);

        // In this case, reject will return from the promise and will catch it in the catch block.
        await Promise.all([10, 20, 30].map((x) => x === 30 ? errPromise : compPromise))

        // In this case, the parameter was deliberately sent as undefined and will still be caught in the catch block.
        await Promise.all([undefined, 'Johnny', 'Alison'].map((x) => x.trim().includes("n") ? errPromise : compPromise))
        

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
    }
}

exec()
```